# Schedule node-cron job to run once everyday without specifying time (once every 24hrs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-cron

I need to run a node-cron schedule once everyday i.e., once every 24hours.
Can I do it without specifying time?

```
var job = new CronJob('0 0 0 * * *', function() {

})
```

Comment: the third parameter is used for hours you can see : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: @Vivek but the hours can be 23 max

Comment: hour start from 0-23

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it without specifying time as cron needs time on which it has to excecute callback function.

You can use "0 0 */1 * *" which will be executed "At 00:00 on every day-of-month"

```
var job = new CronJob('0 0 */1 * *', function() {
   // here goes things you want to execute 
})
```